# C++ vector of strings, why assignment results in same char references?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, vector, char

I am currently learning C++, and I wanted to manually input values to a vector of strings, processing each character before storing it. This is the code I used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, height = 5, width = 5;
    vector<string> lab;
    lab.resize(height, "");
    string s;

    //For input reference
    cout << endl << "Input data:" << endl << "01234" << endl;

    //Input values
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        getline (cin, s);

        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) 
        {   
            //Process char [...]
            lab[i][j] = s.at(j);
        }
    }

    //Show Matrix
    cout << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {   
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            cout << lab[i][j] << " "; 
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    //Show Addresses
    cout << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {   
        cout << "String Addr: " << (void*) &lab[i] << " | Chars Addr: ";
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            //cout << lab[i][j] << " "; 
            cout << (void*) &lab[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem was that the characters inside the strings have the same address (I don't know why). Here is an example of one execution of the program:

```
Input data:
01234
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
ddddd
abcde

a b c d e 
a b c d e 
a b c d e 
a b c d e 
a b c d e 

String Addr: 0x8fe8008 | Chars Addr: 0xb773260c 0xb773260d 0xb773260e 0xb773260f 0xb7732610 
String Addr: 0x8fe800c | Chars Addr: 0xb773260c 0xb773260d 0xb773260e 0xb773260f 0xb7732610 
String Addr: 0x8fe8010 | Chars Addr: 0xb773260c 0xb773260d 0xb773260e 0xb773260f 0xb7732610 
String Addr: 0x8fe8014 | Chars Addr: 0xb773260c 0xb773260d 0xb773260e 0xb773260f 0xb7732610 
String Addr: 0x8fe8018 | Chars Addr: 0xb773260c 0xb773260d 0xb773260e 0xb773260f 0xb7732610
```

At the end you can see that the addresses of the chars are the same, while the ones for the strings are different. The final matrix in the example should have been:

```
a a a a a
b b b b b
c c c c c
d d d d d
a b c d e
```

But instead, it is:

```
a b c d e 
a b c d e 
a b c d e 
a b c d e 
a b c d e
```

While I already solved the problem, using the `+=` operator instead of assigning using `[]`, I still don't know exactly what hapened with the code above. Why does the chars have the same reference?

Comment: before the line `lab[i][j] = s.at(j);` do you resize `lab[i]` at all?

Comment: Hint: Replace `lab[i][j]` with `lab[i].at(j)` and you should get an `out_of_range` exception

Comment: @gx_ Yes, but that's really not what you want.  If his type were `std::vector<std::vector<char> >`, he'd get error messages at runtime, with an abort (assuming the correct compiler flags), but for some reason, the compilers I have access to don't do this with `std::string`.  (I'd consider this a bug.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are going out of bounds on your assignments:

```
lab[i][j] = s.at(j);
```

`lab[i]` is valid but `lab[i][j]` for any `j` is out of bounds, because all the strings in your vector were initialized to `""`, an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that although you've resized the vector you have not resized any of the strings inside it, they are all still zero length. So when you do

```
lab[i][j] = s.at(j);
```

you are accessing outside of the bounds of the string at `lab[i]`.

This should work

```
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) 
    {   
        //Process char [...]
        lab[i].push_back(s.at(j));
    }
```

This version adds each char to the string as it's processed.

Comment: Though, since he already has the input in the form of a `std::string`, it seems silly to do a `push_back` for each character instead of doing a single `+=` operation.

Answer (score 1):

This code is invalid

```
//Input values
for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    getline (cin, s);

    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) 
    {   
        //Process char [...]
        lab[i][j] = s.at(j);
    }
}
```

Each string of the vector is empty so you may not access its elements by the subscript operator.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid working on separater characters in string. You havent event set the size before calling `operator[]` on your string, it does not even work when I check with g++/mingw.

This line is bad:

```
 lab[i][j] = s.at(j);
```

`lab[i]` as not been constructed with a size, so it is not required to be able to contains anything.

Use (without the `j` for loop):

```
lab[i] = s;
```

Or even better:

```
//Input values
for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    getline (cin, lab[i]);
}
```